# Applying Runge Kutta method to $ma= \frac12 pdav^2-gm$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I am going to calculate/program a ball falling downwards (with air resistance), which means I am going to calculate this:

$$ma= \frac12 pdav^2-gm.$$

The problem with trying to learn it online which I have been doing for some time now is that they all have the formula in front of them, and they just plug in numbers. I have a lot of small stupid questions because of this so bear with me.

First I am solving for $a$, the acceleration:

$$a=\dfrac{\frac 12pdav^2-g}{m}$$

Then I turn it into a second order differential equation: 
$$x''=\frac{\frac 12pdax'^2-g}{m}$$

I then rewrite it into a system of first order differential equations:

$$\begin{cases}\frac {dv}{dt} &=& \frac{\frac 12pdav^2-g}{m}\\
\frac {dx}{dt} &=& v \end{cases}$$

If I actually were to solve for these numerically would I then find the position at $x(t)$, and the velocity at $v(t)$?

What are my functions $f()$, and $g()$? How do I know what kind of variables go inside there? if $f()$ is a function of $f(t,x,v) = \frac {dx}{dv}$ the only variable I can insert is $v$. Is it therefore only a function of $v$? So $f(v) = \frac {dx}{dv}$? Or if not, which order are they in? $f(t,x,v) = \frac {dx}{dv}$ or for example $f(x,v,t) = \frac {dx}{dv}$?

In all the examples I have seen you are given a function, and where to put the numbers. I haven't come across anything non specific that teaches you what to do. If I know the order of the function, I guess I can follow the formula but if not I am stuck.

[image]

In other examples where you only have two variables, the formula changes and becomes: 
[image]

Does it matter whether you calculate $k_0,$ or $l_0$ first and then continue that path $k_0$,$l_0$,$k_1$,$l_1$  or $l_0$,$k_0$, and so on? Because it seems like I can calculate either of them first without getting into problems.

[image]

Comment: I realized I have not solved correctly for a, the acceleration, but I can't edit it.

Comment: The differential equation $$x''= bx''(x')^2-g$$ for some constants $(b,g)$ can be rewritten as $$x''=\frac{g}{b(x')^2-1}$$ that is, $$z'=f(z)$$ with $$f(z)=\frac{g}{bz^2-1}$$ You should now be able to apply Runge-Kutta algorithm to this **one-dimensional** system.

Comment: @Did I am very sorry, the A in 2pdav2(Air resistance), is actually the Area of the object. A constant. I am still confused though, because I have these small questions which I need answered so I can apply them to whatever system I want.

Comment: Simpler yet then, since $f(z)=bz^2-g$ with no other change.

Comment: Where did the Masses go? Why is there no divide by M?

Comment: What? $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: There is m*a = air.resistance-g*m. So you divide by m on both sides right? Unless you sat that dividing by m is equal to times 1/m, and insert it into that b.

Comment: Indeed, $b=pda/(2m)$ (even though I do not quite know what is $a$ in this formula, since you said it was not equal to the acceleration $a$ in the LHS but a constant).

Answer (score 1):

The first point to realize is that you have a system of first-order differential equations in $t$ and a *collection* of dependent variables  $\mathbf{y} = \{y_1,y_2, \ldots y_m\}$.  In your case, $m=2$ and  $\mathbf{y}$ is $\{x,v\}$.   The system 
is then described by the dynamics
$$
\frac{d \mathbf{y}}{dt} = \mathbf{f} (t, y_1, y_2, \ldots,y_m)
$$
That is, what you and your books are calling $f$ and $g$ can be thought of as a function returning $m$ different values for the rate of change of the $m$ dependent ($y)$ variables.
This is why your equations have $k_i$ and  $l_i$ in them; $k_i$ relates to a (time) derivative of $x$ and $l_i$ relates to a derivative of $v$.  I would prefer to call $f$ and $g$ as $f_1(t,x,v)$ and $f_2(t,x,v)$.

The Runge-Kutta algorithm starts by considering a step in time of $\frac12 h$ which translates to $\mathbf{y}_{n+\frac12} = \mathbf{y}_{n} + \mathbf{k}_0$ 
with
$$
\mathbf{k}_0 =\left( \frac12 h v, \frac12 h \frac{\frac12\rho A v^2 - g}{m}\right)
$$
You should recognize the first component as $k_0$ and the second as $l_0$.

Then you are again taking  to a step in time of $\frac12 h$ (from the same starting time, only this time using the time derivatives obtained at $t = t_0 + \frac12 h$ by using the values of $\mathbf{k}_0$ you just computed. Because your system has on $x$ or $t$ dependence, this gives an equation which is very nearly the same as before: 
$$
\mathbf{k}_1 =\left( \frac12 h (v + \frac12 h), \frac12 h \frac{\frac12\rho A \left[v+\frac12 h  \left( \frac12 h \frac{\frac12\rho A v^2 - g}{m}\right) \right]^2 - g}{m}\right)$$
The number in the square braces comes from the seond component of  $\mathbf{k}_1$

$\mathbf{k}_2  $ is done similarly, using $\mathbf{k}_1$ to "step" instead of $\mathbf{k}_10$.  Finally $\mathbf{k}_3$  takes a time step of the full $h$.

the last part of Runge-Kutta forms the unique compination of $\mathbf{k}_0$ through $\mathbf{k}_3$  that makes the solution exact in this interval of length $h$, up to errors of order $h^5$.

Comment: I still don't understand Mark. If you take a look up at the other K0's in my thread there is no 1/2, but in your example there suddenly is. I tried experimenting with my code anyway: gyazo.com/3ce707a5a78709fdddeeba2b0dab5f66 I think I have tried every combination in every order, switching up the variables, switching up the functions, etc with no luck so far. As it is right now my X_n actually almost get's the right value, except the right value is, is the X_n I get times 100 every time. My x_n becomes 0.000981, but the right answer is 0.0981 looping through once.